# Find indexes of two lists

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I have two numpy lists:

```
x = ['A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'V', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A']
y = ['1', '2', '1', '1', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

How can I find indexes when simulataneously `x` equals `'A'` and `y` equals `'2'`?

I expect to get indexes `[1, 5]`.

I tried to use:
`np.where(x == 'A' and y == '2')` but it didn't help me.

Comment: Are they numpy *arrays*, or *python* lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the list to numpy array in order to use vectorized operation such as `==` and `&`:

```
import numpy as np
np.where((np.array(x) == "A") & (np.array(y) == "2"))
# (array([1, 5]),)
```

Shorter version (if you are sure that x and y are numpy arrays):

```
>>> np.where(np.logical_and(x == 'A', y == '2'))
(array([1, 5]),)
```

Answer (score 3):

pure python solution:

```
>>> [i for i,j in enumerate(zip(x,y)) if j==('A','2')]
[1, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with lists:

```
idx1 = [i for i, x in enumerate(x) if x == 'A']
idx2 = [i for i, x in enumerate(y) if x == '2']
list(set(idx1).intersection(idx2))
```